Why am I getting the error "Resource at url not found" with this importxml function?
The function is
=importxml("https://scryfall.com/search?as=grid&order=name&q=type%3Aaetherborn+color%3E%3DW+%28game%3Apaper%29+legal%3Avintage","//strong[1]")
This should say "0 cards found"
This one works fine for me, and I'm not sure what's the difference.
=IMPORTXML("https://scryfall.com/search?as=grid&order=name&q=type%3Aadvisor+color%3E%3DW+%28game%3Apaper%29+legal%3Avintage","//strong[1]")
I've tried replacing //strong[1] with a more direct xpath but I get the same answer. I'm wanting the response "0 cards found"

The website is returning an HTTP 404 Not Found response, which is the web's way of telling you "that thing does not exist".
Some websites take the effort to make this response look pretty, and some don't.  This particular website does.  It's dressing up the response to make it look like a regular search result.
But the =importxml function doesn't care; it sees the 404 Not Found header and aborts immediately, not bothering to look at the page content.
